# Insomnia : Need to get a variable in a JSON Array which does not have name

Tags: arrays, json, insomnia

Here is the JSON I have and I would like to get the ID Value using a Filter (JSONPath)

[{"ID":1}]

I cannot modify my input.

[image]

[image]

I tried a lot of things and did a lot of researches but say that I need to give my array a name.

Comment: What language are you working in? PHP has no problem with this. https://3v4l.org/R0vSf

Comment: I see lots of examples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus) that use `$`. Based on that I'd say: try `$.[0].ID` or perhaps `$..[0].ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I had to use $.[0].ID